# How to connect pair to arrays to contain the same index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, indexing

I am developing a quiz app for iOS and I keep the questions in an array and the answers in another array. So far I have been able to have a label display a random question from the question array with arc4random. However when I try to set up buttons to display random answer choices they don't match the assigned question. For example, the question at index = 0 in the question array goes with the array of answers at index = 0 in the answers array and so. How can I make it to where whenever a random question is generated the correct answers display with (in other words how do I make sure they both always have a matching index that is pulled by the arc4random method or whatever method)?

Here is some of my code:

```
//random question generation function
func randomQuestion() {
    index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
    questionLabel.text = questions[index]

let questions = ["Who is Thor's half brother?", "What is the name of Thor's hammer?", "What is Thor's father name?"]

//Each correct answer is placed at index 0 (right answers are Atum, Mjolinr, & Odin)
var answers = [["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Odin's Staff"], ["Odin, "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]]


//This variable is used in a later function that helps randomize wear the correct answer will be placed randomly from a set of buttons
var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0


IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {



print ("Correct!")
}

else {

    wrongSeg()
print ("Wrong!")

    }

    if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
    {
        newQuestion()
    }
}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
newQuestion()


}




//function that displays new question
func newQuestion()
{

//countdown timer section




randomQuestion()

rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

//create a button
var button:UIButton = UIButton()

var x = 1

for index in 1...4
{
    //creat a button
    button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

    if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
    {
        button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)



    }

    else {




        button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)

    x += 1
        }
}


currentQuestion += 1
```

}

Comment: instead of array of answer , you can take Dictionary with question as key and answers as value!

Comment: Can you randomize a dictionary?

Comment: I haven't tried it. but i thin you can randomise array of dictionary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dictionary` to assign the answers to the appropriate questions.

```
let QADictionary = ["Who is Thor's half brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"],"What is the name of Thor's hammer?": ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Odin's Staff"], "What is Thor's father name?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"] ]


//Get question list
let questionsList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
// Random question index
let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionsList.count)))
// Fetch question from list
let question = questionsList[index]
// Assign to label
questionLabel.text = question

//Get the answer for the randomly chosen question. Because you question is the `Key` for the dictionary.
let answer = QADictionary[question]
```

Comment: Is there a way to individually access each value of the key? Like if I wanted to individually set each answer value to a button? (So I would have four buttons that each display an answer value that is paired to the question key)

Comment: @CaptainCode `let answer = QADictionary[question]` will give you the answers array. iterate the array to get the values of the question. And `questionLabel.text` has your question, that is the key of your dictionary.

Comment: Could you give an example by using my code that I've given as an example? I'm still confused as to how I would access each value (answer) of each key (question)

Comment: @CaptainCode      `if let answer = QADictionary[question] {
        
           let option1 = answer[0]
           let option2 = answer[1]
            let option3 = answer[2]
        }`

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense

Answer (score 2):

@Saurabh Prajapati 's suggestion is correct for your requirement.

**Step1:** First store your questions and answers in a dictionary.

**Step2:** Make an array with the key of your dictionary as follows.

For example your dictionary name is quizDic.

```
 var questionsArray = quizDic.keys.Array
```

**Step3:** Find your questionsArray count and pass that value to the random generated function.

**Step4:** Then Access you correct answer from quizDic based on randomly selected key from the questionsArray.